# Rails, checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I don't know how to return checked values. There is my code

```
controller:

  def index

    // there I would like to get checked cities

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @cities }
    end

  end


viewer:

  <%= render 'form' %>


_form:

  <% for cities in Database.find(:all) %>
  <div>
    <%= check_box_tag cities.city1 %>
    <%= cities.city1 %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
@cities = Database.find(:all)
params[:cities].each do |city|
  ...
end
```

and

```
<% for city in @cities %>
<%= check_box_tag "cities[]", city.id %> <%= city.city1 %>
<% end %>
```

but got error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Your problem seems to be similar to HABTM through checkboxes try

```
<%form_tag "some_action", :method => :post do %>
  <% Database.find(:all).each do |city| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "cities[]",city.city1, :false %>
      <%= citiy.city1 %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

and inside controller

```
def some_action
  if !request.post?
    @cities = Database.find(:all)
    render 'view'
  else
    params[:cities].each do |city|
      ...
    end
    redirect_to view_path
  end
end
```

Comment: One more thing it's a bad idea to make requests to the db from view You should do that inside controller

Comment: I tried request to db from controller, but I got error. I think is something wrong with params[:cities].each do|city| .. end 
because without this I can check boxes.

Comment: you don't make any difference between POST and GET requests To make params[:cties] avaliable you have to send data from your form

Answer (score 2):

To do this you'll want to iterate over the list of cities and add a check_box_tag with the name "cities[]" for each.

I usually provide the list as a variable to use in the view.  Do the Database.find in the controller.

```
<% for city in @cities %>
  <%= check_box_tag "cities[]", city.id %> <%= city.name %>
<% end %>
```

Note - if no checkboxes are checked, nothing will be submitted for the param - ie, there won't be a 'cities[]' param at all.  You may need to add this depending on the logic of your search.  If so, add to the form...

```
<%= hidden-field_tag "cities[]", '' %>
```

Or you can handle it in the controller.

Comment: something wrong with  params[:cities].each do |city| ... end
because without this I can check boxes (but only check, not get params)

Comment: The error is due to the @cities variable being nil.  Create @cities in the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Put a debugger in your controller code. What happens when you inspect your params? Is there anything similar to params[:cities]? If so, what's in there?